# Trying to find out all occurrences where printf format is not followed

Tags: linux, grep

Currently I am using below linux command to find out the format where format specifier is given but there is no argument.

`LOG_WARNG("Status key %d not found in the me");`

`grep -rnE "LOG_([A-Za-z])+" app/|grep -i "%"|grep -v ","`

How can i find out below logs using some script?

`LOG_XYZ("xyasdfa %d", )`

and

`LOG_XYZ("xyasdfa %d %d", abc)`

and

`LOG_XYZ("xyasdfa %d", abc, )`

I don't care about performance and I just need this to be done in any scripting language.

Comment: You do realize that this nearly impossible to solve correctly without actually parsing the python code, because you can't know the actual number of elements in an iterable that is passed as argument, right? What I mean is, your second example would be correct if `abc = (1.0, 2.0)`

Comment: I have removed python from the tags. I just wanted some kind of grep script to find out the logs which follow the pattern mentioned in the question.

Comment: @nomanpouigt Not exactly what you are asking, but you could replace '%' with `str.format`. In such case `pylint` checks the format string arguments for you. There might be a small performance penalty.

Comment: Alright, given that the number of format arguments in the logmessage and the supplied actual arguments must match, it is still impossible, becasue regexes are a subclass of [context free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which is important in this case because CFGs have no notion of memory. You need to count the number of arguments and make sure they match, and that is inherently impossible. You may hack your way around that by only allowing a maximum number of arguments, e.g. 3, but the regex is going to look horrible and will be very hard to debug.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your comment as answer? With some example code? I don't care about performance.

Comment: @nomanpouigt but you have just removed the Python tag ... Example. `LOG_XYZ("xyasdfa {} {}".format(abc))`. `pylint` checker would complain: `Not enough arguments for format string (too-few-format-args)`

Comment: I agree with VPfB, using pylint to solve this is probably easier than trying to find a regex. It might look like a trivial problem, but it really isn't.